# How can I get the distance and time from L.Routing.control?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I am drawing a route on a leaflet map, it works good and in the control it shows the distance and estimated time of arrival. Is there a way to extract both of them and save them?

The code for the L.Routing.control

```
function getroute() {
myroutewithout = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(window.my_lat, window.my_lng),
    L.latLng(window.job_p_lat, window.job_p_lng)
  ],show: true, units: 'imperial',
 router: L.Routing.mapbox('API-KEY-HERE'),
  createMarker: function(i, wp, nWps) {
    if (i === 0 || i === nWps + 1) {
      // here change the starting and ending icons
      return mymarker = L.marker(wp.latLng, {
        icon: operatoricon
      });
    } else {
      return job_start = L.marker(wp.latLng, {
        icon: jobicon
      }); 
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: What do you mean "save" them - store in a variable to use elsewhere? What plugin are you using for routing?

Comment: Im using leaflet-routing-machine, and just for instance just alert them.

Comment: I don't see a straightforward way to expose that data, but the [docs for the Router](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#irouter) suggest that you can provide a callback that has an array of routes - each route contains an array of instructions, which include distance and time. You might be able to iterate over that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve that using the code from this [issue](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/150)

```
var routeControl = L.Routing.control({...});
...
routeControl.on('routesfound', function(e) {
   var routes = e.routes;
   var summary = routes[0].summary;
   // alert distance and time in km and minutes
   alert('Total distance is ' + summary.totalDistance / 1000 + ' km and total time is ' + Math.round(summary.totalTime % 3600 / 60) + ' minutes');
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z81e2gym/)

Comment: Yes works great apart from it only shows time in minutes and misses out the hours! But I can work with that, thankyou